# Is an 8 hour layover in Russia (SVO) long enough to leave the airport?

Tags: layovers, moscow

On my way to Paris, I will have an 8-hour layover in Moscow (SVO) in Russia from 5 in the morning until 1 in the afternoon.

Will I have enough time to leave the airport and spend a few hours in Moscow and still be able to get back, clear security and make my connecting flight in time, or should I just find ways to keep myself occupied at the airport?

I will be traveling on a US passport

Comment: What visa on arrival? [You cannot obtain a visa upon arrival, so you must apply for your visa well in advance. If you arrive in Russia without an entry visa, border authorities will not permit you to enter the country, and you could face immediate return to the point of embarkation at your own expense, and possible ban on entering Russia for a period thereafter.](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/russia.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If you don't have Russian Visa, you wont be able to get out to the city.
2. Moscow have huge traffic jams ;) 
   It's can take few hours to get into the center, and few hours back. 
   I wouldn't risk to miss my flight, even though I'm Russian.

However you probably can make it and see Moscow for 1-2 hours, but I don't think it worth it to spend time/money for visa, and to be in such a hurry :)

P.S.: Moscow never sleep.

Answer (score 3):

8-hour layover is completely enough to see some sights in the center of Moscow. To avoid traffic jams just use "Aeroexpress" (airtrain). It departures every 20-30 minutes and it takes about 40 minutes to get from SVO to Belorusskaya railway and metro stations - which is not far from the center of Moscow. So, you'll have about 4-5 hours for sightseeing.

I used to travel a lot and I haven't noticed any difficulties during passport control in SVO. So, I think you have a good chance to wander in the center.

Comment: As above, worth adding that US citizens require a visa to enter Russia.  The cost of the visa is in excess of $100 and it takes some time to obtain.

Comment: Yes, of cause. Unfortunately it is so..

Answer (score -1):

You do not need a transit visa if less than 24 hours layover. Passport and plan ticket to you destination is only required.

The only 2 restrictions apply is that if you are going in/out of Belarus or the Crimeana Pennisula.

Look up under Aeroflot visa and passport to back up this claim.

https://www.aeroflot.ru/us-en/before_and_after_fly/airport/visa_and_passport_control

Comment: I don't believe this allows you to pass immigration. The Aeroflot link you provided says you can't even change terminals without a visa, and Timatic agrees. You could connect without a visa, but you would need a visa to leave the airport as the OP proposed to do.